# Ninject - how to reference a parent object from an injected child object

Tags: ninject, circular-dependency, circular-reference

I am trying to use Ninject to compose an object graph in which a parent object contains a child object and the child object also maintains a reference to its parent.

Without dependency injection, it would look something like this:

```
public interface IParent { }
public interface IChild { }

public class Parent : IParent
{
    public Parent()
    {
        Child = new Child(this);
    }

    public IChild Child { get; private set; }       
}

public class Child : IChild
{
    public Child(IParent parent)
    {
        Parent = parent;
    }

    public IParent Parent { get; private set; }
}
```

I would like to be able to configure Ninject bindings to support this relationship, such that multiple instances of `IParent` may be instantiated in transient scope, with each instance being automatically populated with an `IChild` instance that holds a circular reference to it.

I have read comments that suggest that Ninject can support circular relationships, but I haven't been able to arrive at a working configuration.

Any suggestions please?

Thanks,

Tim.

Comment: Well at least I tried... and I did not succeed as well, there are not many reasources to this topic. It's because you should not have circular dependencies in the first place. You should probably consider using different design.

Comment: @Viktor - yes, I also don't feel comfortable about the circular reference but I haven't found any other design that can do what I need. In any case, I have found a reasonable workaround to the problem (posted below). It will be interesting to see whether anyone else posts a real solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case anyone else runs into this issue, here is the solution I used (although I accept that there may exist better ones):

```
public interface IParent { }

public interface IChild
{
    IParent Parent { get; set; }
}

public class Parent : IParent, IInitializable
{
    public Parent(IChild child)
    {
        Child = child;
    }

    public IChild Child { get; private set; }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        Child.Parent = this;
    }
}

public class Child : IChild
{
    public IParent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

The key is to implement Ninject's `IInitializable` interface in the parent class, which causes it to receive a callback after composition has completed. In this callback handler, the parent instance simply assigns the child object a reference to `this`.

Comment: Very late to the party here but if anyone else stumbles here then there is a solution plus working code [on this page](http://www.emidee.net/index.php/2010/08/23/ninject-use-one-database-session-per-view-model/).